# object lifetime in multithreaded environment

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer, lifetime

Following [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I created a console app to exercise:

```
public class Program
{
    //private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        short_running_method();

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void short_running_method()
    {
        // Normally, the timer is declared at the class level, 
        // so that it stays in scope as long as it is needed. 
        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method,   
        // KeepAlive must be used to prevent the JIT compiler  
        // from allowing aggressive garbage collection to occur  
        // before the method ends. You can experiment with this 
        // by commenting out the class-level declaration and  
        // uncommenting the declaration below; then uncomment 
        // the GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) at the end of the method. 
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer; 

        // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use 
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring 
        // before the method ends. 
        //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }


    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

I understand (correct me if i am wrong) the timer object declared at class-level is alive as long as the Program is running and the event keeps firing infinitely. By commenting out the class level declared timer object and uncommenting the declaration within the short_running_method, I suppose the atimer object should be garbage collected after certain amount of time if GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) is not used and the event should stop firing. However, in my experiment the event seems never stop, even after 30 minutes it's still getting raised. Can someone clarify why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the **strong reference** from the event source to the event listener:

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```

So, you might be looking for the **weak event pattern** here: 
[Weak Event Patterns on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx)

Also, to **stop the timer** you can use:

```
aTimer.Stop();
```

> You can also stop timing by setting **Enabled** to false.
>
> The signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a ThreadPool thread, so the event-handling method might run on one thread at the same time that a call to the Stop method runs on another thread. **This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after the Stop method is called.** The code example in the next section shows one way to work around this race condition.
>
> [MSDN: Timer.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) is not necessary if strong reference to event listener is used? The code is actually from MSDN article and they didn't realize this. The weak event pattern is totally new to me. Well, another item on my To Study list. Thanks.

Comment: The event handler is a static method. Are you sure there is a strong reference to it?